# is it possible to change the look of the map

Tags: android, google-maps

Is it possible in android to change the look of the map like in the javascript way ?
like here : http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmaps/wizard/index.html

i haven't found this answer yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, sorry, the Google Maps add-on for Android does not have that level of flexibility.